# Unrecognized selector sent to instance: setting an @property id to a tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

So I am trying to integrate my image accessor code into my application but for some reason I keep running into this exception:

```
2014-04-14 21:20:34.876 1k[21130:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setParent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ab7e8a0'
```

When I debug, the error occurs when I try to set `tableViewController.parent=self;` (this is the way that the later controllers can access the `UploadViewController`, The code for UploadViewController that is calling the segue looks like this

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ToTableView"]) {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];
    TableViewController *tableViewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0];
    tableViewController.parent = self;
    tableViewController.groups = (NSArray *)sender;
}}
```

And the header file of TableViewController looks like this:

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <AssetsAccessorDelegate,      UIAlertViewDelegate> {
      AssetsAccessor *assetsAccessor;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id parent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *groups;

@end
```

I had first found this functionality through Github and now am trying to integrate it into my code I don't understand why it is now giving me this problem.

This error can happen for so many different reasons that I am really at a lost for how to approach this.

Comment: The error is because you are calling `setParent:` on `UITableViewController`. This is correct because that class has no such method. You added that method (via the `parent` property) to your `TableViewController` class. Perhaps you didn't set the class for the table view controller in Interface Builder.

Comment: `navigationController.viewControllers[0]` indicates the root view controller of navigationController, is it what you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting `tableViewController` isn't really a `TableViewController`. Put a breakpoint at this line of code:

```
tableViewController.parent = self;
```

...then in the debugger window, type the following:

```
po tableViewController
```

po means "print object". You should see something like this:

```
<TableViewController: 0x100615120>
```

If instead it looks something like this:

```
<UITableViewController: 0x100615120>
```

...then that's your problem. If so, then `navigationController.viewControllers[0]` isn't the right class. Look at where in the code (or storyboard) that is set up.

Comment: The error confirms that it isn't really a `TableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

`navigationController.viewControllers[0]` is an instance of UITableViewController, not your TableViewController class.